# Database design - Lookup table

Tags: database-design

how do you label your "code", sequencial number (1,2,3,4...n)?

Example

My DeviceType lookup table holds mobile devices, and has the following attributes

```
Id
Code
Name
```

Comment: Can you explain more of what you're trying to do? Are you looking for **code** to be a sequential, unique id for each record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you can tolerate gaps in the sequence, you can use any of the suggestions in other answers and you can also use `SEQUENCE` in Oracle, `IDENTITY` in IBM DB2 or auto-increment fields in MS SQL Server.

If, however, you absolutely need to avoid gaps, even in the concurrent environment, things suddenly become much less straightforward. In essence, you gonna have to identify the "candidate" value, then try to insert it and then be prepared to retry the whole process if a concurrent transaction inserted it before you.

BTW, could you use `code` as primary key and drop the `Id` altogether?

Comment: Sure! I was thinking of dropping Id, since Code is unique, can never change, however it does then the primary key would be using varchar instead of int. is that a problem? Also code does not have a fixed length ie "IPAD" "IPHONE" "ANDROID"

Comment: @001 In your question, you said: *"how do you label your "code", sequencial number (1,2,3,4...n)?"*. So it was my understanding that `code` is a sequential INT, not VARCHAR. Perhaps you should edit your question and make it more clear?

Comment: @001 To try to answer you comment: What you have here is two keys: one natural (`code`) and one surrogate (`id`). Both strategies (keeping the surrogate vs. not keeping it), have pros and cons but this is no place to list them all. For some hints, see the bullet points at the bottom of my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665735/how-do-i-organize-such-database-in-sqlite/7668726#7668726

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can characterize fields (i.e., columns) as "auto-increment," which will update your `code` field as you insert news rows into the table. I believe this is common to many, if not all, SQL systems. Have a look [**over here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for a description of the MySQL operation.

Answer (score 0):

In postgreSQL the column type would be serial ( or bigserial ) to accomplish the same thing.  Then in your inserts leave the serial column out and the db engine will auto-increment for you as Pete's excellent link said.

Answer (score 0):

Most of us don't build tables that use an id number--which is usually sequential--and an additional code that's also sequential. There's no point to it.

If code is a sequential, unique number, drop the id column and make code the primary key.

Comment: I was thinking of dropping Id, since Code is unique, can never change, however it does then the primary key would be using varchar instead of int. is that a problem? Also code does not have a fixed length ie "IPAD" "IPHONE" "ANDROID"

Comment: The fact that "code" is a fairly short VARCHAR() shouldn't matter enough to matter. If you use an id number, you'll always have to use a join; using "code" you'll never need a join. I'd make "code" the primary key. Others will have other opinions. If you *do* decide to keep the id number, make sure you declare the "code" column unique.